# node.js architecture - how to share middleware (bodyparser)

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

To keep 'app.js' separated from other functionality I've restructured my node application like so:

*app.js*

```
// declare dependencies, etc
var server = http.createServer(app);

var controllers = require('./controllers');
controllers.set(app, server, passport);
```

*controllers/index.js*

```
var socketController = require('./socketController.js');
var passportController = require('../config/passport.js');
var routeController = require('./routeController.js');
var routes = require('../routes');

// server side data
var sessions = [];
var userPrivileges = [];

module.exports.set = function(app, server, passport) {
    /**
     * Routes
     */
    // serve index and view partials
    app.get('/', routes.index);
    app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);

    // redirect all others to the index (HTML5 history)
    app.get('*', routes.index);

    routeController.set(app, passport, sessions, userPrivileges);
    socketController.set(app, server, sessions, userPrivileges);
    passportController.set(passport);
};
```

*controllers/routeController.js*

```
module.exports.set = function(app, passport, sessions, userPrivileges) {

    // route to test if the user is logged in or not
    app.get('/loggedin', function(req, res) {
        res.send(req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user : '0');
    });
};
```

My problem is when I call GET `/loggedin` it's returning a bunch of HTML - it seems like bodyparser is not being activated. I've tried declaring bodyparser in `routeController.js` but that hasn't seemed to help. How would I share this middleware across these different files?

Answer (score 1):

Your `app.get('*', routes.index);` route is handling the request before it ever gets to any other routes. You might try moving that route *after* all other routes